# Which button to press?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I have two buttons and one gold ingot. Button A has probability $p_1$ of giving you the gold each time you press it. Button B has prob $p_2$.

It costs $c_1$ to press button A and $c_2$ to press button B. You want to find the gold with the minimum expected cost.  To do this you would compute $p_1/c_1$ and compare it to $p_2/c_2$ and repeatedly press whichever button gives the bigger ratio.

But then you learn that each time you press a button, the cost of pressing that button again goes up by $d>0$.

What should you do?

The most obvious strategy is to recalculate the two probability/cost ratios and each time choose the button with the largest ratio. Is this greedy strategy optimal and if so, how can you prove it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I downvoted this. It looks like you just copied from a text book without attempting the problem yourself. For example the bottom part says "how can you prove it?" as if copied from a worksheet or something.

Comment: @SuzuHirose OK. This is just my writing style. The question is entirely my invention.  My attempt to solve it is to consider the greedy algorithm which I proposed but I don’t know how to go about proving it is optimal.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer, received a comment that my answer was incorrect, and then deleted my answer.  I thought that linearity of expectation was sufficient to verify that the *greedy algorithm* was optimal.  **I was wrong**.  ...see next comment

Comment: As mjqxxxx indicated in now deleted comments: $$\cdots$$ "There's only one ingot, and the price to push a button increases with each repetition, so both the payoffs and the costs are dependent on the previous turns... linearity of expectation alone isn't enough to prove the result." $$\cdots$$ "consider a related problem where the cost to push a particular button becomes zero after the first press. Then the optimal (non-greedy) strategy is to choose the button with the lower initial cost, regardless of the probabilities, and press it until you win."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The greedy strategy is optimal.

---

A state of the game can be described as a pair of integers $(i, j)$ where $i \geq 0$ and $j \geq 0$ —  how many times button $A$ and button $B$ were pressed, respectively.

A strategy for the game corresponds to an infinite path on integer lattice, originating from $(0, 0)$, and always going either one square right, or one square up. Its vertices correspond to strategy states. Here's an example of a strategy that starts with button presses $ABBAABABAAABB...$

[image: example strategy]

Note, that there could be infinitely many optimal strategies, e.g. if $p_1 = p_2$ and $c_1 = c_2$.

**Lemma 1.** Take any state $(i, j)$ and consider a modified game in which this state is initial. Any strategy for this game has finite expected cost and there exists an optimal strategy. (Proof omitted)

**Lemma 2.** Optimal strategy does not end with pressing the same button indefinitely. (Proof omitted).

In terms of paths it means, that path corresponding to an optimal strategy does not end with a horizontal or vertical ray, in other words, it contains infinitely many number of "turns".

**Lemma 3.** Consider any L-shaped part of an optimal path, specifically: a part that starts with $n \geq 1$ edges going right and ends with a single edge going up. This corresponds to a segment of optimal strategy $...\underbrace{AAA...A}_\text{n times}B...$.  Let the costs of buttons $A$ and $B$ in the first vertex of this L-shaped part be $\bar{c}_1$ and $\bar{c}_2$. Then $\bar{c}_1 / p_1 \leq \bar{c}_2 / p_2$. (Proof will be given in the end).

**Observation.** Lemma 3 is formulated for strategy substrings $AAA...AB$, but, if it is true, by symmetry the same should also apply for substrings $BBB...BA$, that is in the first vertex of such substrings $\bar{c}_1 / p_1 \geq \bar{c}_2 / p_2$.

If we combine lemmas 2, 3 and the observation, we see that any vertex of some optimal path is the first vertex of some "L shape". Which means in every vertex a greedy choice was made. The greedy strategy is ambiguous in the case when there's an equality, that is when $\bar{c}_1 / p_1 = \bar{c}_2 / p_2$. If we follow the proof of lemma 3 we should be able to see, that both choices in such vertices has the same expected cost, hence both lead to optimal strategies.

---

#### Proof of Lemma 3

See the picture below. The red path $...AAA...AB...$ is the optimal one. The green path $BAAA...A$ is alternative "detour". Because red path is optimal, changing part of it to this "detour" cannot improve it.

[image: lemma 3 proof]

Let $q_1 = 1 - p_1$ and  $q_2 = 1- p_2$. Let expected cost of the end state $(i + n, j + 1)$ be $M$ (this is the cost of optimal strategy for a game that starts in that state).

Consider the first state of L-shape part, state $(i, j)$. If we start the game from this state and follow the red path, its expected cost is

$$
(\text{Red}) = \color{blue}{\bar{c}_1 + q_1 (\bar{c}_1 + d) + q_1^2 (\bar{c}_1 + 2d) + \ldots + q_1^{n-1} (\bar{c}_1 + (n-1)d)} + q_1^n \bar{c}_2 + q_1^n q_2 M,
$$

if we follow the green path, then it's expected cost is

$$
(\text{Green}) = \bar{c}_2 + q_2 \left( \color{blue}{\bar{c}_1 + q_1 (\bar{c}_1 + d) + q_1^2 (\bar{c}_1 + 2d) + \ldots + q_1^{n-1} (\bar{c}_1 + (n-1)d)} + q_1^n M \right).
$$

Red path is optimal, which means $(\text{Green}) \geq (\text{Red})$. In this inequality summand $q_1^n q_2 M$ cancels out. We separate $p_1, q_1, \bar{c}_1$ to the right and $p_2, q_2, \bar{c}_2$ to the left:

$$
\frac{\bar{c}_2}{p_2} \geq \frac{\color{blue}{\bar{c}_1 + q_1 (\bar{c}_1 + d) + q_1^2 (\bar{c}_1 + 2d) + \ldots + q_1^{n-1} (\bar{c}_1 + (n-1)d)}}{1 - q_1^n}
= \frac{\bar{c}_1(1 + q_1 + q_1^2+...+q_1^{n-1}) + \overbrace{q_1d + q_1^2 \cdot 2d + ... + q_1^{n-1} \cdot (n-1) d }^{\geq 0} }{p_1(1+q_1+q_1^2 + ... + q_1^{n-1})} \geq \frac{\bar{c}_1}{p_1}
$$

QED.

From proof we see, that equality is only possible when $n = 1$ or $q_1 = 0$ or $d = 0$.

---

Note. The proof actually can be extended to games, where cost increases as a monotonous function instead of as an arithmetic progression, as long as lemma 1 holds.

Comment: Thank you very much!